# unable to delete accounts in paypal sandbox

Tags: checkbox, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Ok so all i want to do is delete two existing paypal sandbox accounts, however i am unable to select the checkbox associated with the accounts.

Normally you would select the checkbox for the account you wish to edit and then select delete. Obviously this isn't an option at the moment as i am unable to interact with the checkboxes.

I have searched all over for an answer to my question and found one person ask the same question, only to receive a response with a link back to the paypal site where the instructions state that you should click the checkbox and select delete account. As i said, I can't do this because it won't let me click the box.

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal recently experienced a known issue on it's developer portal which affected the sandbox account creation and deletion. However, the issue is now resolved and you should be able to delete your accounts.

If you are still having this issue, please do file a ticket at  https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask and our MTS engineer would further troubleshoot on this.